# How can I do math with words in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I am trying to write a program that can do math with English words.

For example, I want to be able to do something like

```
"four thousand and three" + "seven thousand and twenty nine"
```

and get output like

```
"eleven thousand and thirty two"
```

Is it possible to do this in jQuery?

Comment: yes, there probably is. what have you tried?

Comment: I tried asking on SO...no luck yet.

Comment: you'll probably need to write a mini dictionary and grammar with logic rules about how you combine the words. I doubt jQuery will be useful though

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, I have written a [jQuery plug-in called Word Math](https://github.com/peterolson/Word-Math) that was made for this exact purpose.

For the example in your question, you can just copy and paste this code

```
alert($.wordMath("four thousand and three").add("seven thousand and twenty nine"));
//alerts "eleven thousand thirty two"
```

and voila! You've performed some word math.

Word Math can also do conversion from Javascript numbers to words and vice versa:

```
$.wordMath.toString(65401.90332)
// sixty five thousand four hundred one and nine tenths and three thousandths and three ten thousandths and two hundred thousandths

$.wordMath("three million four hundred and sixty seven thousand five hundred and forty two").value
// 3467542
```

[You can read more about how to use the Word Math plugin on its readme page](https://github.com/peterolson/Word-Math#readme)

**EDIT:** There is now a version of Word Math that does not depend on jQuery. To use it, you should download the `wordMath.vanilla.min.js` file on the gitHub repository instead of the `wordMath.jquery.js` file.

The usage of the jQuery-less version is exactly the same as the jQuery version, except that you do not need the `$.` prefix in the calls. In other words, instead of doing

```
$.wordMath("fifteen").add("eighteen")
```

you would instead write

```
wordMath("fifteen").add("eighteen")
```

Comment: I'm curious why this needs to be a jQuery plugin? I don't see what power jQuery has over plain old js here?

Comment: @Daniel and the second word? :P

Comment: jQuery's power over JS and the second word are one and the same, young grasshopper.

Comment: @Chimoo: After having a quick look at the source, I don't see any jQuery dependence so I guess it's easy to use it without jQuery.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for that, I thought that might be the case

Comment: @Daniel: jQuery provides many advantages regarding DOM manipulation / traversal, event handling and Ajax, but these are all things not needed in your case.

Comment: I use jQuery all the time, but I'll add to the list of people who think it is ridiculous that this is done as a jQuery plugin when clearly there is no dependency or value added by jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the library but if you want to write your own code you could start with something like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var equation = "one plus two";
var arrayOfWords =  equation.split(" ");
var functionToEvaluate = "";

for(i in arrayOfWords){
    functionToEvaluate = functionToEvaluate + GetNumericOrSymbol(arrayOfWords[i]);
}

var answer = eval(functionToEvaluate);
alert(answer);
//Then your method GetNumericOrSymbol() could so something like this.

function GetNumericOrSymbol(word){
    var assocArray = new Array();
    assocArray['one'] = 1;
    assocArray['two'] = 2;

    //rest of the numbers to nine

    assocArray['plus']='+';

    //rest of your operators

    return assocArray[word];
}
</script>
```

Something like taking the Array out of the function call would help optimize it. Had a lot of fun writing this.

Comment: After you get your answer then you could go through the reverse process to make the string.

Answer (score 2):

As you know, you cannot perform mathematical operations on the strings themselves, so you need to start by converting your text into numerical values.

After you perform the mathematical operations on the numeric values, you can convert the values back into strings and output the result.

Comment: D'oh! I was hoping for "go to [URL], install [awesome] plugin, copy/paste text from SO question into .js file, and voila!"